# Dynamic Allocation and Reallocation of Memory

Tags: c, memory-management

This is a code snippet of a larger program. I tried to simplify it as much as possible.

This code identifies certain particles and stores them in a list which corresponds to a certain processor.
Besides that I count the number of particles per processor that are already in the list.
After the work is done I want to use the message-passing system *MPI* to send the particles in the list to other processors (not shown here).

I would like to know:

- Is the process of allocation and deallocation of memory correct?
- Is the code robust?
- Can this be simplified?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIM 2

typedef struct{
    double m;   
    double x[DIM];
    double v[DIM];
    int id;
} Particle;

typedef struct{
    double **list;
    int *counter;
} ParticleList;

void generateParticles(Particle *p, int N);
void buildList(Particle *p, ParticleList *plist, int numprocs, int N);

int main() {
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    // Generate data, print data
    int N = 50;
    Particle *p = (Particle*)malloc(N*sizeof(*p));
    generateParticles(p, N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("id: %d m: %lf x: %lf %lf v: %lf %lf\n", p[i].id, p[i].m, p[i].x[0], p[i].x[1], p[i].v[0], p[i].v[1]);
    }

    // Fill lists of every processor
    int numprocs = 4;
    ParticleList plist;
    plist.list = malloc(sizeof(double*)*numprocs);
    for(int k=0; k<numprocs; k++)
        plist.list[k] = malloc(sizeof(double)*1);
    plist.counter = calloc(numprocs, sizeof(int));
    buildList(p, &plist, numprocs, N);

    for(int k=0; k<numprocs; k++){
        printf("Processor %d Particles in list %d\n", k, plist.counter[k]);
        for(int c=0; c<(DIM*plist.counter[k]); c++){
            printf("%lf ", plist.list[k][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // deallocate memory
    for(int k=0; k<numprocs; k++){
        free(plist.list[k]);
    }
    free(plist.list);
    free(plist.counter);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

void buildList(Particle *p, ParticleList *plist, int numprocs, int N){
    for(int k=0; k<numprocs; k++){
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("k %d, i %d\n", k, i);
            if(rand()%10 < 5){
                plist->counter[k] = plist->counter[k] + 1;
                plist->list[k] = realloc(plist->list[k], (DIM*plist->counter[k])*sizeof(plist->list[k][0]));
                int d=0;
                for(int j=(plist->counter[k] - 1)*DIM; j < (plist->counter[k] * DIM); j++){
                    plist->list[k][j] = p[i].x[d];
                    d++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

double frand(){
    return (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX; 
}

void generateParticles(Particle *p, int N){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int d=0; d<DIM; d++){
            p[i].x[d] = frand();
            p[i].v[d] = frand();
        }
        p[i].m = frand();
        p[i].id = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code would have benefited with `allocateList()`, `allocateParticles()`, `freeList()`, `freeParticles()` functions, rather than trying coding it all up in `main()`.

**allocation and deallocation of memory correct?**

Allocations lack error checking.  This is the big issue as it also impacts proper de-allocation code.

`plist->list[k] = realloc(plist->list[k], ....` leak memory should the allocation fail.

`DIM*plist->counter[k])*sizeof(plist->list[k][0])` could overflow `int` math, yet work well with `size_t` math.  See re-ordering below.

**Robust-ness**

Use `size_t` instead of `int` for indexing. As "code snippet of a larger program", the array sizes may be very large.  The best type for array indexing is `size_t`, an unsigned type.

```
// for(int d=0; d<DIM; d++){
for(size_t d=0; d<DIM; d++){
        p[i].x[d] = frand();
        p[i].v[d] = frand();
    }
```

**Simplification**

C does not require the cast nor `()` with `sizeof object`

```
// Particle *p = (Particle*)malloc(N*sizeof(*p));
Particle *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);

// I prefer `sizeof` first, especially  for math that may benefit with `size_t` math.
//                   v---------------v all size_t math  
Particle *p = malloc(sizeof *p * N * N);
// vs                v---v may overflow `int` math
Particle *p = malloc(N * N * sizeof *p);
```

Simplify coding, review and maintenance.  Is `plist.list` a `double *`?  Why bother attempting to co-coordinate the type of member `list` with the `malloc()` call which may be in another file?

```
// plist.list = malloc(sizeof(double*)*numprocs);
plist.list = malloc(sizeof *(plist.list) * numprocs); 

// plist.counter = calloc(numprocs, sizeof(int));
plist.counter = calloc(numprocs, sizeof *(plist.counter));
// or 
plist.counter = calloc(numprocs, sizeof plist.counter[0]);
```

The `*1` is curious and lacks benefit

```
// plist.list[k] = malloc(sizeof(double)*1);
plist.list[k] = malloc(sizeof *(plist.list[k]));
```

---

`buildList()` would benefit with re-write - IMO, is is not simple to follow.  As code lacks guiding comments, I am left to guess how to simplify it without losing meaning.  Sample idea with some style improvements.

```
// Style issue: Avoid wrapping presentation code and horizontal scroll bars
void buildList(Particle *p, size_t n, ParticleList *plist, size_t numprocs) {
  for (size_t np=0; np<numprocs; np++) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
      printf("np %zu, i %zu\n", np, i);
      if (rand()%10 < 5) {
        size_t new_count = plist->counter[k] + 1;
        void *new_ptr = realloc(plist->list[np],sizeof plist->list[np][0] * DIM*new_count);
        if (new_ptr == NULL) {
          TBD_ErrorHandler();
          // ...
        }
        plist->list[k] = new_ptr;
        plist->counter[k] = new_count;
        // I think the following is the same - I had trouble following original code.
        for(size_t dm = 0; dm < DIM; dm++) {
          plist->list[pn][new_count + j] = p[i].x[dm];
        }
      } // endif
    }
  }
}
```

`"l"` in `"%lf"` not required - more of a style issue

```
// printf("id: %d m: %lf x: %lf %lf v: %lf %lf\n", 
printf("id: %d m: %f x: %f %f v: %f %f\n", 
  p[i].id, p[i].m, p[i].x[0], p[i].x[1], p[i].v[0], p[i].v[1]);
```

---

Sample `ParticleList_free()`

```
void ParticleList_free(ParticleList *pl) {
  if (pl) {
    if (pl->list) {
       for(int k=0; k<numprocs; k++) {
         free(pl->list[k]);
         pl->list[k] = NULL; // ***
       }
       free(pl->list);
       pl->list = NULL; // ***
    }
    free(pl>counter);
    pl>counter = NULL; // ***
    free(pl);
  }

  // Sample usage
  ParticleList *pl = ParticleList_alloc();
  buildList(p, pl, numprocs, N);
  ....
  ParticleList_free(pl);
  pl = NULL; // ***
```

*** Useful for debugging, but not needed for production code.  By setting to `NULL`, errant uses of pointers are typically more likely to be found.  YMMV.

Comment: is the part where the deallocation takes place correct? `for(int k=0; k<numprocs;k++)free(plist.list[k]);}free(plist.list);free(plist.counter);free(p);` So far i don't get an error. But maybe I miss something. Thank you!

Comment: Looks OK, yet I see weaknesses as the free'ing  does the loop and `free(plist.list);free(pl‌​ist.counter);` without first checking if `plist` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, so I just do in the loop `if(plist.list[k] != NULL)` and outside `if(plist.counter != NULL)`?

Comment: @Samuel Sample code posted.

Comment: I think in your loop where you free the memory an `i` is missing. And should it not be `pl->list[i]` and `pl->counter` instead of `p->list[i]` and `p->counter`?